# recursion limit error python, when calling function x amount of times

Tags: python, recursion

I have some code that gets some resources from the internet like so:

```
def ScrapeFromUrl(url):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        html = response.read()
        urlToFile('main', html.decode('utf-8'))
        webSoup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        mainContent = webSoup.find("div", { "id" : "main" })
        generalImdbData['nextPageUrl'] = mainContent.findChildren()[0].findChildren()[2].find('a').get('href')
        generalImdbData['totalResults'] = int(re.search( r'(\d+)(?!.*\d)', mainContent.findChildren()[0].findChildren()[2].span.contents[0]).group(1)) 
        generalImdbData['loadedResults'] = int(re.search( r'\-(\d+)', mainContent.findChildren()[0].findChildren()[2].span.contents[0]).group(1))

        actorsContainer = mainContent.findAll("div", {"class": "lister-list"})[0]
        for actor in actorsContainer.findAll("div", {"class": "lister-item"}):
            SearchResultsToActorObjects(actor)

        urlToFile('data', str(mainContent))
        GoToNextPageUrl(generalImdbData['loadedResults'], generalImdbData['nextPageUrl'])

def GoToNextPageUrl(loadedResultsCount, nextUrl):
    if loadedResultsCount >= generalImdbData['totalResults']:
        for a in actorObjectList:
            a.printActor()
            a.insertIntoDB()
        actorObjectList.clear()
    else: 
        for a in actorObjectList:
            a.printActor()
            a.insertIntoDB()

        actorObjectList.clear() 
        ScrapeFromUrl(generalImdbData['baseUrl'] + nextUrl)
```

and the function gets called like this:

```
ScrapeFromUrl(generalImdbData['originalSearchUrl'])
```

but the problem i am having is that these functions get called about 50k times. So i get this recursion limit error.

How do i prevent this from happening?

Comment: The main way I know to keep the recursive stack small is to subdivide a problem of size `n` into two subproblems of size `n/2` at each stage, rather than into subproblems of size `1` and size `n-1`.  I don't have time to try to work it out for your case (hence I'm putting this in as a comment), but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42192532/2166798 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrapeFromUrl()` calls `GoToNextPageUrl()`, which calls `ScrapeFromUrl()`, which calls `GoToNextPageUrl()`, etc etc etc.

This creates an infinite recursion.

You need to reorganize your code so the functions don't endlessly call each other.

Comment: well it is not infinite the moment the `if statment` in `GoToNextPageUrl` is `true` then the recursion stops. and yes this only happens after 10's of thousands of times. But that doesnt make it infinite. Next to this i am asking on advice on how to prevent this. "reorganize your code" is a bit general pointing into a specific dimension would help a lot more.